# How to update table and add column value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to add column and column value this table? (this table is update and adding)

Database A:

Table Student

```
ID  Name    Age
----------------
1   John    24
2   Albert  23
3   Kelvin  24
4   Carol   25
```

after update:

```
ID  Name    Age    SchoolNo
---------------------------
1   John    24       1245
2   Albert  23       1245
3   Kelvin  24       1245
4   Carol   25       1245
```

Comment: Both are *Database A* - first of all, this is a **table** (not a database), and secondly - are really both Table A ?

Comment: A is a table in the database named A.After the second table is updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a column to an existing table, use the `ALTER TABLE` 
statement

```
 ALTER TABLE table_name
      ADD column_name column_definition;
```

Your example:

```
ALTER TABLE A
  ADD SchoolNo int;
```

You can then use an `INSERT INTO` statement to add in your values.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (column1)  
  VALUES (value1);
```

Your example:

```
INSERT INTO A (SchoolNo)  
  VALUES (1245);
```

Comment: Hi. Is it okay if I write?   ==>  ADD SchoolNo char(4);

Comment: @K.E sure, you could do that